# Can't run pg in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

When I try to start a container like this:

```
  db:
    container_name: database-pg
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:5432:5432
    restart: always
    logging:
      <<: *logging_default
    volumes:
      - datavolume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./backend/db/migrations/0001-init.up.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0001-init.up.sql
      - ./envs/ropsten/seed.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0002-seed.sql
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
```

I see this:

```
2021-01-09 12:00:48.362 UTC [89] FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2021-01-09 12:00:48.362 UTC [89] DETAIL: Password does not match for user "postgres".
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 99: "host all all all md5"
2021-01-09 12:01:47.477 UTC [91] FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2021-01-09 12:01:47.477 UTC [91] DETAIL: Password does not match for user "postgres".
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 99: "host all all all md5"
2021-01-09 12:01:47.909 UTC [92] FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2021-01-09 12:01:47.909 UTC [92] DETAIL: Password does not match for user "postgres".
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 99: "host all all all md5"
2021-01-09 12:01:47.988 UTC [93] FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2021-01-09 12:01:47.988 UTC [93] DETAIL: Password does not match for user "postgres".
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 99: "host all all all md5"
2021-01-09 12:01:48.540 UTC [94] FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2021-01-09 12:01:48.540 UTC [94] DETAIL: Password does not match for user "postgres".
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 99: "host all all all md5"
2021-01-09 12:01:48.627 UTC [95] FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2021-01-09 12:01:48.627 UTC [95] DETAIL: Password does not match for user "postgres".
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 99: "host all all all md5"
```

I cannot understand why this is happening. Why does postgres show this error at all, what else should the password be at startup.

Comment: Why i see `pq: password authentication failed for user "postgres"` when do i start the trust mode? `- POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust`

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to run postgres using your configuration (I've just removed the logging and volumes section) and everything was fine.

It seems to me that you put the `POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust` config after initializing the database. There is a note in the official docker image readme:

> This optional variable can be used to control the auth-method for host connections for all databases, all users, and all addresses. If unspecified then md5 password authentication is used. On an **uninitialized** database, this will populate pg_hba.conf via this approximate line:
> `echo "host all all all $POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD" >> pg_hba.conf`

So, to fix your problem you should either delete your data and recreate the database or mount your own updated pg_hba.conf file:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    db:
        container_name: database-pg
        image: postgres
        ports:
        - 127.0.0.1:5433:5432
        restart: always
        environment:
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
        command: postgres -c 'hba_file=/var/lib/postgresql/pg_hba.conf'
        volumes:
        - datavolume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        - ./backend/db/migrations/0001-init.up.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0001-init.up.sql
        - ./envs/ropsten/seed.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0002-seed.sql            
        - ./hba.conf:/var/lib/postgresql/pg_hba.conf
```

where hba.conf:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust

# warning trust is enabled for all connections
# see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/auth-trust.html
host all all all trust
```

Comment: I did recreate the database and it didn't help. Of course, I added the result I needed by making changes in user privileges using SQL. But this is just a crutch. I still do not understand why this is happening, I suspect that this may be due to the fact that I use macos, although I still have no idea how this could be

Comment: @mrsubject that's really strange. I use macOS too, so I don't think it's the reason. Did you try to mount updated pg_hba.conf ?

Comment: No, and I do not want to create my own image, I just want to use the official ready-made copy. And, yes, for some reason this image does not seem to respond to environment variables, although if you connect to the image and view the variables, then I actually see the variables in my environment. I tried to completely delete the image, and reinstall the installation, but all to no avail, only a crutch in the form of `ALTER ROLE postgres WITH PASSWORD 'postgres'` helps.

Comment: Surprisingly, I can connect to the database locally, without a password, it works true. But it only works in a local environment. If I try to do this outside of the container then a problem occurs.

Comment: You don't need to create your own image to use your pg_hba.conf. You just put another line in your volumes section. I've updated my answer